# Keyboard Emulating barcode reader

Tags: c#, .net, hardware, point-of-sale, opos

I'm using the Microsoft.PointOfService libraries to interact with POS hardware. Although documentation about compatible hardware is thin on the ground, I've read in places that **all** keyboard emulating barcode scanners should be compatible.

so now I have my barcode scanner (Wasp WSR-455), which emulates the keyboard, and I was wondering if anybody here knows how to make the posdm tool recognise it, or another way I can program against a `barcodeScanned` event.

D.R

Answer (score 2):

You don't bother with that, nor can you, when they emulate a keyboard.  Either you or the user has to make sure the focus is always on a specific text box so the scanner output goes to the right place.  This certainly removes a great deal of flexibility in your UI, you'd really do need a scanner that you can connect to directly over, say, a USB port.  They usually emulate a serial port, you'd use the SerialPort class.

Comment: I was considering as a last resort to use the DirectInput (or similar) libraries to get input notifications. However I would have preferred to not have to do this myself... =/ thanks @HansPassant